# Not allowing me to push object into an array

Tags: angular

I'm working with Angular. I'm trying to push an object into an array but it giving me errors. It says that 
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined**
That is the code below. Article is an object.

```
articles: Article[];
addArticle(newTitle: HTMLInputElement, newLink: HTMLInputElement): boolean {
    this.articles.push(new Article(newTitle.value, newLink.value, 0));
    newTitle.value = '';
    newLink.value = '';
    return false;
}
```

What can I do?

Comment: declare articles before you try to push to it

Comment: I already did. I declared it as: **articles: Article[];** but the error is still there.

Comment: you defined it not declared :) do this `articles: Article[] = []`

Answer (score 0):

So if it worked for you and as I saw at least few similar questions latly.
If you have `TypeError: Cannot read property 'whatever' of undefined` that means you didn't declared some property.
This is declaration:

```
someProperty: SomeType = []
```

if you have this its only definition:

```
someProperty: SomeType
```

and trying do any operation on it will result in above error.