# How to access property inside of array with typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array of properties and when I try to make a loop, I can see the object in the logs, but if I try to access them I got an error.

this is my class:

```
export class M{
id: number;
carName : string;

constructor(Id:number,CarName:string){
    this.id = Id;
    this.carName = CarName;
   }
}

export class C{
Values: M[];
}
```

So when I log the `this.C.Values` I can see it, but if I try to access, I got undefined !

```
this.httpClient.getC().subscribe(x => 
  {
   this.C = x;     
   console.log(this.C.Values);


  })
```

Even looping I got the same result!.

```
 this.Data = this.C.Values; 
 this.Data.forEach(element => {
     console.log(element);

   });
  })
```

Comment: Do you see anything if you do `console.log(x.Values)`? Anyway, add to your question what you see in the console if you do `console.log(x)`.

Comment: This kind of question is some kind of plague I saw it multiple time few last days https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62349908/not-allowing-me-to-push-object-into-an-array/62364977#62364977 you need to declare `Values: M[] = []` to be able to use it

Comment: I do see.The array of M.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: If I do element.Value I get undefined

Comment: Its probably the order and because of the subscribe, your code is async. Where is this.httpClient.getC() called from and where is the forEach?

Comment: @NathielPaulino with the answer, is your forEach logging anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare property befor using it:

```
export class C {
  Values: M[] = new Array<M>()
}
```