# ReactJs: How to map an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, object

I get data(object) while fetching user info from API. It quite looks like,

```
{
    "id":"1111",
    "name":"abcd",
    "xyz":[
        {
            "a":"a",
            "b":"b",
            "c":"c"
        },
        {
            "a":"e",
            "b":"f",
            "c":"g"
        }
    ],
    "email":"abc@xyz.com",
    "phone":"0123456789"
}
```

here I store(JSON response) the data by using `useState` hook. Now I can easily access any index by typing data.id or data.name, But the problem is if I map data.xyz like that

```
(data.xyz).map((xyz,index) => (//something)
```

it says,

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

I use `Object.keys(data.xyz).map` as this is an object but not working. How can I access/loop through xyz index?

Comment: another one when you mistake definition with declaration https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62349908/not-allowing-me-to-push-object-into-an-array/62364977#62364977

Comment: You need to post more code , how you are setting and how you are accessing the xyz array, then you can get the better solution. You can access one property but not the other may be possible that xyz property doesn't exists in your main object or it is not an array.

Comment: @Vivek I already explain how i store that data. I use `useState` Hook like `const [data, setdata] = useState([])` to define it and after fetching use `setdata(json)` to store.

Answer (score 1):

How do you initialize the data?
When you fetch to API, this is an async event, so probably in the first render data.xyz is undefined.
Maybe you can do:

```
const [data, setData] = useState({ xyz: [] });
```

Comment: Actually i get all the data from an API, not just only xyz. define the state like `const [data, setdata] = useState({})` then assign by `setdata`. `useState({ xyz: [] })` can not do anything

Comment: Since you don't know if array exists, you can check if so... data.xyz && data.xyz.map((item, index) => ())

Answer (score 1):

```js
let data = {
  id: "1111",
  name: "abcd",
  xyz: [
    {
      a: "a",
      b: "b",
      c: "c",
    },
    {
      a: "e",
      b: "f",
      c: "g",
    },
  ],
  email: "abc@xyz.com",
  phone: "0123456789",
};

let xyz = data.xyz.map((xyz, index) => {
  console.log(xyz);
  return xyz;
});
console.log("XYZ ==>", xyz);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess you have defined data as follow:

```js
class SomeClass {
  data: {
    "id":"1111",
    "name":"abcd",
    "xyz":[
        {
            "a":"a",
            "b":"b",
            "c":"c"
        },
        {
            "a":"e",
            "b":"f",
            "c":"g"
        }
    ],
    "email":"abc@xyz.com",
    "phone":"0123456789"
  }
}
```

Instead of doing this:

```js
class SomeClass {
  data = {
    "id":"1111",
    "name":"abcd",
    "xyz":[
        {
            "a":"a",
            "b":"b",
            "c":"c"
        },
        {
            "a":"e",
            "b":"f",
            "c":"g"
        }
    ],
    "email":"abc@xyz.com",
    "phone":"0123456789"
  }
}
```